# Webpack require/import image without extension

Tags: regex, webpack

I want to import/require an image that doesn't have an extension. Is this possible? For example currently I can import jsx files without writing the extension. What if I want to do the same for image files or other type of files that lack file extension?

E.g. require('./avatar.png') will work. What I want to work is require('./avatar')

Answer (score 3):

I'd *strongly* advise against doing this, as writing the extension makes it more explict exactly what's being imported.

For example, if you had `avatar.js`, `avatar.png` and `avatar.css` in the same folder, is it easy to tell what `import ... from './avatar'` will give you? Having similarly-named files with different extensions is not an uncommon convention.

But, either way, you can add the extensions you want to [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) in the webpack config, like so. Try to be responsible with it.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.png', '.jpg', /* ... */]
  }
}
```

Comment: another point in favor of full extension import is, when the project grows you want to make a full search for `avatar.png` and that will be easy, but if you import without extension it will be much harder to find globally